# Repeating of tests' subsequence using TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I want to repeat performing of some subsequence of the test methods in my TestNG project. Let's say I have the following test class:

```
@Test
class Abc
{
   public void a() {}
   public void b() {}
   public void c() {}
   public void d() {}
   public void e() {}
}
```

And the following testng.xml:

```
<suite name="My suite" verbose="1">
    <test name="simple test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Abc">
                <methods>
                    <include name="e"/>
                    <include name="d"/>
                    <include name="c"/>
                    <include name="b"/>
                    <include name="a"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How I can repeat performing of subset of test that begins from the "c" method, so that after the last method in test sequence is completed the methods "c", "b", "a" will be called ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

1. `groups` and `dependsOnGroups`;
2. `dependsOnMethods`;
3. or `priority`;
4. use `Factory`;
5. Run TestNG programitically.

All of them will help you to order you tests if you really needs it.
See [code](https://github.com/RocketRaccoon/TestNG-Examples/blob/master/src/test/java/RunTestSubSequence.java) and [xml](https://github.com/RocketRaccoon/TestNG-Examples/blob/master/src/test/resources/testng.xml) example.

Comment: Yes, using the constructions above I can control the test execution flow. But notice that I also need to repeat execution of some test methods.

Comment: It depends on kind of test you want to execute, I've added some extra options

Comment: Please give me a short code example where execution of the "c,b,a" test methods repeats after execution of the last test method ("a")

Comment: So just e,d,c,b,a,c,b,a? Without any conditions?

Comment: Let the repetitions' number of the "c, b, a" test methods depends on some field of object

Comment: @Antonio, I attached example using groups